# Default sound output device forgotten after restart

Tags: sound

I'm running a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04. I have three audio outputs on my computer: a USB headset, S/PDIF through motherboard, and line out through motherboard. They are listed in that order in the Gnome sound settings pane.

I prefer line out to be used by default, so I've selected it in the output tab, and it works fine after selecting it.

Here's the problem: I would expect that if I restart the computer, line out would continue to be the default output device, but the actual behavior is different. Ubuntu partially forgets this preference upon restart.

Sound *does* play via line out after a restart, but if I try to adjust the volume via media keys, it adjusts by *headset* volume instead of line out. Furthermore, if I open the sound settings, I see that my USB headset is selected rather than line out. Clicking on line out again fixes everything until the next time I restart.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Same issue here, super annoying

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1204000/158095

Answer (score 0):

Install **Pulse Audio Volume Control**.  Click on Configuration and make your selection there.  Then go to your Sound icon and match the settings.

You can find it in the repository:

```
$ sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

Comment: Sadly that didn't work. I installed pavucontrol, clicked the green checkmark for "set as fallback" next to my line out device, then confirmed that line out was selected in the Gnome sound settings.

When I restarted my computer, the same problematic behavior occurred. Sound played through line out, but my volume control affected my USB headset instead of line out, and my USB headset was selected both as the default fallback in pavucontrol and Gnome sound settings.