# Wrong audio output after unlocking

Tags: sound

*I don't believe this is a duplicate of [Ubuntu changing default audio output after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840473/ubuntu-changing-default-audio-output-after-suspend), because I'm not suspending the PC.*

I've got 3 audio outputs (analogue headphones, USB digital amp, USB headset) and 2 audio inputs (headset, webcam mike) on my desktop PC.

When I unlock the PC, it has switched the default audio output to the USB headset, even though I'd prefer to use the analogue headphones.

Oddly, however, music (via Clementine) continues to come out of my headphones; it's just that the volume controls on my keyboard change the volume on the USB headset.

I *suspect* (but don't know) that it might be because the USB headset is connected via the hub on my monitor, which powers off when the PC is locked, and presumably results in a USB connection event when powered back on.

How can I fix this?

(Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: Which locker software does Ubuntu use? (I have used Xubuntu where that is configurable.)

Comment: Anyway, when using xubuntu-desktop, you could work this around.

Comment: Can you try to connect the USB headset to your computer directly or to another hub?

Comment: I _could_, but that's not a long-term solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*tl;dr? Scroll to the end.*

#### Monitoring for screen lock/unlock

Adapted from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1080607/158095), this monitors for screen lock/unlock:

```
#!/bin/bash

watch="type=signal,interface=org.gnome.ScreenSaver"
screen_locked_signal="boolean true"
screen_unlocked_signal="boolean false"

dbus-monitor --session "$watch" | ( \
    while read signal; do
        if [[ "$signal" =~ "$screen_locked_signal" ]]; then
            echo "Screen Locked"
        elif [[ "$signal" =~ "$screen_unlocked_signal" ]]; then
            echo "Screen Unlocked"
        fi
    done)
```

---

#### PulseAudio

You can find out which source and sink are currently being used as follows:

```
$ pactl info | grep -E 'Default (Source|Sink):'
Default Sink: alsa_output.usb-Logitech_Inc._Logitech_USB_Headset_H340-00.analog-stereo
Default Source: alsa_input.usb-Logitech_Inc._Logitech_USB_Headset_H340-00.analog-stereo
```

(This is my USB headset)

You can switch source and sink as follows:

```
$ pactl set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
$ pactl set-default-source alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
```

(Use analogue output and input)

You can get a complete list of sources and sinks with `pactl list short sinks` and `pactl list short sources`, but there are extra entries in there. It's probably best to switch using the UI tools and then use `pactl info` to discover the appropriate ones.

---

#### Final script

It results in a script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# GNOME
watch="type=signal,interface=org.gnome.ScreenSaver"

# XFCE
# watch="type='signal',interface='org.xfce.ScreenSaver'"

screen_locked_signal="boolean true"
screen_unlocked_signal="boolean false"

# PulseAudio: use pactl
_get_default_sink() {
    pactl info | sed -n 's/^Default Sink: \(.*\)/\1/p'
}

_get_default_source() {
    pactl info | sed -n 's/^Default Source: \(.*\)/\1/p'
}

_set_default_sink() {
    pactl set-default-sink "$1"
}

_set_default_source() {
    pactl set-default-source "$1"
}

last_sink=$(_get_default_sink)
last_source=$(_get_default_source)
echo "sink is $last_sink; source is $last_source"

# Watch for screensaver D-Bus signals
dbus-monitor --session "$watch" | ( \
    while read signal; do
        if [[ "$signal" =~ "$screen_locked_signal" ]]; then
            # Screen locked: remember the current default sink and source
            last_sink=$(_get_default_sink)
            last_source=$(_get_default_source)
            echo "Screen Locked; sink was $last_sink; source was $last_source"
        elif [[ "$signal" =~ "$screen_unlocked_signal" ]]; then
            # Screen unlocked: restore the last default sink and source
            _set_default_sink "$last_sink"
            _set_default_source "$last_source"
            echo "Screen Unlocked; sink is $(_get_default_sink); source is $(_get_default_source)"
        fi
    done)
```

---

#### Automatically starting the script

To ensure that this script runs as soon as you log in, you can use `gnome-session-properties` and add a startup application (I called mine "Monitor Screensaver") pointing to the script. It'll create a `~/.config/autostart/monitor-screensaver.desktop` file containing the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/home/roger/bin/monitor-screensaver
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_GB]=Monitor Screensaver
Name=Monitor Screensaver
Comment[en_GB]=
Comment=
```

Comment: If you use `xfce4-screensaver` (in latest Xubuntu) then you could use `watch="type='signal',interface='org.xfce.ScreenSaver'"` in the script, but maybe that is not needed as the screensaver might not affect to pulseaudio in any way.

Comment: I suspect that my problem is this: The screensaver immediately sends my monitor into standby, which disconnects the USB hub. When the monitor comes out of standby, the USB reconnection causes the "new" audio devices to be chosen.

I don't know whether the standby behaviour is specific to the GNOME screensaver, but knowing the D-Bus filters for other screensavers might be useful to those using them.

Comment: I wonder, if using the commands I gave in my answer instead of the _get and _set commands in yours in the script would work or is there some race condition?

Comment: I don't know; once I'd got my solution working, I didn't feel the need to try yours. It's a good idea, though, which is why I upvoted it.

Comment: Thanks! I had the same problem, except that in my case it wasn't the sink that needed setting but the card profile, so I needed to modify the script. My version for this is here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1450325/339875

Answer (score 1):

Another way to deal with this is via PulseAudio configuration.

You could run

```
pactl unload-module module-switch-on-connect
```

before locking, and

```
pactl load-module module-switch-on-connect
```

after unlocking. (`pacmd` could be used instead of `pactl`.)

Alternatively, you could disable (read: comment out) loading the module on `default.pa` configuration file; see `man 5 default.pa`. Then you have to switch default device manually.

Answer (score 1):

An easier solution is to comment line `load-module module-switch-on-port-available` from `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and then restart pulse with `pulseaudio -k`

Source : https://askubuntu.com/a/228623/654555

Comment: This works well for me and is a very simple solution.