# Set default audio output when there's only one sink

Tags: sound, 22.04, pulseaudio, alsa

I fresh-installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (after previously using 18.04). The sound configuration menu has these output choices, of which the second choice (the S/PDIF) is the one I use, and choosing it makes the audio work just fine.

[image: audio output menu]

But after each reboot, the audio output is reset to the HDMI output, and I need it to default to the S/PDIF. The solutions I've found (and used on previous installations) involve choosing the right sink for Pulseaudio, but I seem to have only one sink now! Output from `pactl list short sinks` is:

```
6   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_0e.0.hdmi-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
```

Output of `aplay -l` doesn't seem to have any trace of the S/PDIF either:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC283 Analog [ALC283 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC283 Digital [ALC283 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

So where is it?! Where do the menu alternatives come from? And how can I set S/PDIF be the default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dug deeper and found two working solutions, of which I'm fully satisfied with number 2.

**Solution 1: Explicit alsa-sink**

I realized that the first two subdevices listed by `aplay -l` are both actually the S/PDIF, because playing sounds from Java (like I do in [my own music player](https://klipspringer.avadeaux.net/)) works with output device set to either `plughw:0,0` or `plughw:0,1` with the LEDs on my DAC changing appropriately according to the sample rate.

To get one of them chosen by default, it works to add

```
load-module module-alsa-sink
load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:0,1
```

to my `~/.config/pulse/default.pa` (copied from `/etc/pulse/`). This adds a ”Built-in Audio” option in the sound output menu, which gets chosen by default. This is then effectively an alias for the S/PDIF option (which is what I find slightly annoying with this solution).

**Solution 2: set-card-profile**

The Pulseaudio command *list-cards* reveals some interesting information. The `pacmd list-cards` output lists a card named  `alsa_card.pci-0000_00_0e.0` which has a *ports* section that contains the line:

```
iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
```

This is produced by `module-udev-detect`, and must be where the sound settings gets the information about the output it lists as an S/PDIF. By looking at the *list-cards* output
with different output selections in the sound settings menu, I found that the difference was in what was set as “active profile”. This, [I found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/462670/set-default-profile-for-pulseaudio), can be changed with `set-card-profile`. Adding

```
set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_00_0e.0 output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo
```

to `~/.config/pulse/default.pa` worked in the sense that I would get the S/PDIF output after `pulsaudio -k`, but after reboot and login, the sound output would *still* be set to HDMI. (Apparently, something else than Pulseaudio initialization alters the card profile setting.) So instead, I deleted my local `default.pa` again and added the command

```
pacmd set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_00_0e.0 output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo
```

as a [startup application](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html.en). That seemed to have done the trick, until the screen saver kicked in… When the screen is awakened from the screensaver, the card profile is *again* changed to something else! The solution I found for this was to create a script that listens for screensaver events, checks the card profile setting when the screensaver is activated, and sets it back to that when the screensaver goes off. The script is a modified version of the one in [this answer (which deals with setting the sink rather than the card profile)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1204120/339875), and looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
    
my_card="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_0e.0"
watch="type=signal,interface=org.gnome.ScreenSaver"
screen_locked_signal="boolean true"
screen_unlocked_signal="boolean false"

_get_active_profile() {
    pacmd list-cards | sed -n 's/^\s*[Aa]ctive\s\s*[Pp]rofile:\s*<\([^>]*\)>/\1/p'
}

last_profile=$(_get_active_profile)

# Watch for screensaver D-Bus signals
dbus-monitor --session "$watch" | ( \
    while read signal; do
        if [[ "$signal" =~ "$screen_locked_signal" ]]; then
            # Screen locked: remember the current profile
            last_profile=$(_get_active_profile)
        elif [[ "$signal" =~ "$screen_unlocked_signal" ]]; then
            # Screen unlocked: restore the last profile
            pacmd set-card-profile "$my_card $last_profile"
        fi
    done)
```

Adding this script as as well to the startup applications gets rid of the screensaver problem.